# Updating user email and password with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a CakePHP application with user registration. On the users page, I want them to be able to update their email and password. THis is my `User` model:

```
<?php

class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            ),
            'range' => array(
                'rule' => array('between', 4, 20),
                'message' => 'Between 4 and 20 characters'
            ),
            'characters' => array(
                'rule' => array('alphaNumeric'),
                'message' => 'Alphanumeric characters only'
            ),
            'unique' => array(
                'rule' => array('isUnique'),
                'message' => 'This username is taken'
            )
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'An email is required'
            ),
            'validEmail' => array(
                'rule' => array('email'),
                'message' => 'Please provide a valid email'
            ),
            'range' => array(
                'rule' => array('between', 5, 64),
                'message' => 'Between 5 and 64 characters'
            ),
            'unique' => array(
                'rule' => array('isUnique'),
                'message' => 'This email has already been used'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            ),
            'range' => array(
                'rule' => array('between', 5, 64),
                'message' => 'Between 5 and 64 characters'
            ),
        )
    );

    public function beforeSave() {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

And I'm using the form helper to create the form:

```
<p>Modify your account settings</p>
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User');
    echo $this->Form->input('currentPassword', array('type' => 'password'));
    echo $this->Form->input('username', array('disabled' => 'disabled', 'value' => $username));
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    echo $this->Form->input('newPassword', array('type' => 'password'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Update');
?>
```

How would I go about checking if the current password is valid, checking if the new email and password pass validation rules and then updating the users record in my users table from within my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new user - UsersController.php:

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
                    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Registration complete. :)'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error... Please try again.'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Editing a user - UsersController.php:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if($this->Auth->user('password') == AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password']){
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }}else{
         $this->Session->setFlash(__('Incorrect password.'));
        }
         else {
        $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
    }
}
```

Just watch for {}. :D

If it doesn't work, try

```
if($this->Auth->user('password') == $this->request->data['User']['password'])...
```

Comment: How does this check if the password the user has entered is the same as what's stored in the database? From what I see, it's assuming it's the same and carrying on.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want something without changing the model and without displaying the hashed password : [Updating user with or without password - CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628742/updating-user-with-or-without-password-cakephp/33630064#33630064)

TL;DR :

```
// add in your view `app/View/Users/edit.ctp`
// a 'fake' field you'll only use on the controller
echo $this->Form->input('new_password');
```

---

```
// add in your controller `app/Model/User.php`
// if we have a new password, create key `password` in data
if(!empty($new_password = $this->request->data['User']['new_password']))
  $this->request->data['User']['password'] = $new_password;
else // else, we remove the rules on password
  $this->User->validator()->remove('password');
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10169608)

Comment: @iismathwizard ok, I've add a `TL;DR` ; thanks for your feedback ;)

Answer (score 0):

you should also present a second password field for confirmation. this is usual for password updates.
for this and also if you want to check against the current password, see this behavior for how you can accomplish that:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/

Answer (score 0):

Ans:

How does this check if the password the user has entered is the same as what's stored in the database?  – James Dawson

You can add the below function in your model.

```
function check_user($check) {
  if(!empty($check["EMail"]) && !empty( $_POST['data']['User']['password'])) 
    {
        $user = $this->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('User.EMail'=>$check["EMail"],'User.IsVerified'=>1)));
      if(empty($user)) {
        return FALSE;
       }
        $Encrypted = md5($_POST['data']['User']['password']);
        if($user['User']['password'] != ($Encrypted)) {
        return FALSE;
        }
    }
        return TRUE;
    }
```

and validate rule

```
'EMail' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => array('email'),
                'message' => 'Please enter valid email address..!',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                'on' => 'login', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),

            'check_user'=>array(
                'rule'=>'check_user',
                'message'=>'Either your Username or Password is invalid',
                'on' => 'login', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
                'last'=>TRUE,

            ),

        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function _update_password() {

        $password_error = false;

        /**
         * Handle post
         */
        if (($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) && isset($this->request->data['User'])) {

            $old_pass_in_db = $this->User->read('password', $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'));

            $old_pass_in_post = $this->Auth->password($this->request->data['User']['old_password']);

            //assign post data
            $this->User->set($this->request->data);


            //validate
            if (trim($old_pass_in_post) != trim($old_pass_in_db['User']['password'])) {
                $this->User->validationErrors['old_password'] = __("Old password do not match.");
            } else {
                unset($this->User->validationErrors['old_password']);
            }

            if ($this->User->validates(array('fieldList' => array('password', 'password_confirm'))) && ($old_pass_in_post == $old_pass_in_db['User']['password'])) {
                $this->User->id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
                if ($this->User->save(array('password', $this->Auth->password($this->request->data['User']['password'])), false)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Password updated successfully.', true), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
                } //end save
            } else {
                $password_error = true;
            }
        }

        $this->set('password_error', $password_error);
    }
```